# How to log json response in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

If I define a response entity class and return it by my rest controller, controller will change this class to json string. I want to log this json string, how to do it? Thanks.

For example:

Response entity class:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResponseEntity {
    String code;
    String message;
}
```

Rest Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping("test")
    public ResponseEntity test(){
        return new ResponseEntity(200,"success");
    }
}
```

I want to record this json response in log

```json
{"code":200,"message":"success"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and handy way is convert it to JSON string manually and then log it. You can convert it to JSON by `ObjectMapper`.

```java
@Log4j2
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @RequestMapping("test")
    public ResponseEntity test() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity entity = new ResponseEntity(200, "success");
        log.debug("{}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity));
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Or you can use [Logstash json_event pattern for log4j](https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout) if you need advanced feature.

Comment: I don't think you need an ObjectMapper for this. The Spring controller will, by default,  convert the EntityResponse to a json representation (provided that it's a rest controller)

Comment: But spring controller doesn't log it.

Comment: yes , you still need a logger but there's no need for an ObjectMapper.
,

Comment: So how do you convert it to JSON in a better way?

Comment: the spring rest controller will do that automatically for you (note the @RestController annotation)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there a better way to get and log the json result from @RestController ?

Comment: what's wrong with the Spring (default) way (it creates a properly formatted json, right)? BTW, I think Spring is still internally using an ObjectMapper.

Comment: So, specifically, what is your suggestion for my answer ? Thank you.

Comment: just replace  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity)  with entity (e.g log.info(entity.toString()) ). You will still need to override toString() method

Comment: So, overriding `toString()` is still need to convert it to JSON manually, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry , I should've  been clearer, (overriding toString() is recommended anyways). It's not necessary to manually convert entity to json when you're returning it from the method but it's necessary for logging.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish you desired behaviour the spring framework offers an utility class which does exactly the requested job for your.

Just declare this:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
      = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
    filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
    filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
    return filter;
}
}
```

And add to your logging file this appender:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
<level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

Same result can be done with this application.properties property

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

this should be enough, but, in case you want a fine grained control on the logging operation you can create your own filter by extending `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` .

Comment: The question was how to log json *responses*.
Your post deals with *requests* only. So. it doesn't answer the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

```
     add this in responseHandler class:--
        package net.guides.springboot.springbootcrudrestapivalidation.response;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
        import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
        public class ResponseHandler {
            public static ResponseEntity<Object> generateResponse(String message, HttpStatus status, Object responseObj) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("message", message);
                map.put("status", status.value());
                map.put("data", responseObj);
        
                return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,status);
            }
        } 
       
        and then this in controller class:_-
        
        @PostMapping( "employees")
            public ResponseEntity<Object> Post(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
                employeeRepository.save(employee);
                try {
                    Employee emp = EmployeeRepository.Post(employee);
                    return ResponseHandler.generateResponse("Successfully added data!", HttpStatus.OK, emp);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS,null);
                }
output
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "dob": "1994-10-17",
        "doj": "2018-10-17",
        "gender": "male",
        "emailId": "abhih@gmail.com",
        "age": "27",
        "phoneNumber": "+918844945836",
        "address": "Dhan",
        "empName": "akash"
    },
    "message": "Successfully added data!",
    "status": 200
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).